# Simulating ShowDialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I'm working on Dialogs in WPF. I want to implement a DialogCenter which is responsible to change Active Window and show my custom dialog.

Here is my DialogCenter:

```
 internal static class DialogCenter<T> where T : IDialog
 {
     public enum DialogResult{
         OK, Cancel
     }
     public static DialogResult ShowDialog<T>()
     {
         ...
     }
 }
```

and :

```
 interface IDialog
 {
     UserControl GetControl();
     ....
 }
```

ShowDialog will get a UserControl and then puts it into a right place.

The Only way to send a response back to calling window is to implement an event and then calling it whenever my job is done in the UserControl (The only way I know).

so whenever i want to call a DialogWindow, I must do such a work:

```
var A = DialogCenter<SomeDialog>.ShowDialog();
A.OnDialogComplete+= AnEventHandler();
```

this will change my execution flow and I must take care of it. the execution flow will be more complicated.

In WindowsForm we have ShowDialog method that will block the current thread until it returns a DialogResult.

how can I implement such a Method?

Comment: The `Window` type in WPF also has `ShowDialog()` defined, can't you simply just call that method on the `IDialog` interface after adding it since the types implementing `IDialog` probably inherit from `Window`?

Comment: The "add event handler" line of code won't work as it is. Your `ShowDialog` method returns an enum value which has no `OnDialogComplete` event. Furthermore, the event subscribing syntax is not correct.

Comment: Alex, I haven't inherited from Window it's a `UserControl`. I want to implement a ShowDialog that will disable current window and then, it just add my UserControl to current Window AS my Dialog and it will act like a Dialog.

Comment: Dymanoid, it was a Psudo-Code and i have Edited know. Actually I want to return an Enum but i can't. ShowDialog will Disable Current Window and it will adds a UserControl to The Window. I don't know when I'm able to return my Enum because it depends on User, the only way to do this work is to add a `While(!FormClosed)` into ShowDialog method; but it is a disaster i think.